# How to port a simple application (which uses only standard libc) to iPhone OS?

Tags: c, objective-c, gcc, multiplatform, ios

There is a simple application written in C, which includes only standard C library functions (from stdio, stdlib, etc.) and Makefile+GCC to build it. Now, I wanna port it to iPhone OS for iPhone/iPads. Will it be seamless or are there any possible incompatibility issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot simply compile your code for the iphone/ipad OS, seeing their apps are written in objective C. Good news though, you can use your C/C++ code in objective C, here is how to do it:

[Introduction to The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html)

So I suggest you start learning some objective C if you really want to port your app. Be warned that all that is UI will have to be re-written with the UIKit, in objective C.

oooo and also, you will need a mac!

Comment: Yes and No.  You *can* just compile C code for the iPhone, because Objective-C *is* C.  You may not be able to *use* all the things you're used to using (like reading from stdin, etc), but it will still compile...

Answer (score 3):

Your primary issue will be how the program displays its output - the support provided by the Standard C Library does not match what is expected of an iPhone application.  You will have to work on those aspects of your program.